# Set RowState of a DataTable row to deleted

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, infragistics, rowstate

I have an `UltraGrid` in my project, and I have an update function on the form to update the data in the database where the data is matching.

The data in the grid is being stored as a `DataTable`. If a row of existing data is deleted from the `UltraGrid`, I want to be able to set the `RowState` of that row in the `DataTable` to 'RowState.Deleted`, so that in the Update function I can check the`RowState`, and if it's a deleted row, then deleted it, otherwise, update the data.

How can I go about doing this? So far, I have the code below, but the count of rows being returned is 1 (or, the current number of rows in the grid) and not 2 (the number there was before I deleted one row).

How and where in the code, do I set the `RowState` of the deleted row to be `RowState.Deleted`? Is there an alternative way of doing it using the `UltraGrid`?

```
dsProducts.Tables.Add(commDt.Copy) -- commDt is the DataTable linked to the UltraGrid
tr = con.BeginTransaction(

  For Each dr As DataRow In dsProducts.Tables(0).Rows
    If dr.RowState = DataRowState.Deleted Then
     Try
```

Comment: You dont need to do any of that,  Just delete the row (`DataRow.Delete()`) and the row state is set.  If you use a DataAdapter, ***it*** will take the appropriate action for each row based on the rowstate: `Dim rows = myDA.Update(dsProducts.Tables(0))`

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not programmatically setting the row to be deleted, that is handled automatically by the `UltraGrid`. By using a `DataAdapter`, do you mean for the actual update/delete query itself? Rather than on `OleDbCommand`?

Comment: This [Searching values via a datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33702351/1070452) shows how to configure and use a DataAdapter (`OleDBDataAdapter` in your case, I guess).  They will "hold onto" Update, Delete etc commands and issue them via the Update method.

Comment: When you remove a row from the `DataTable` you ***can't*** check the `RowState` property as it doesn't exist anymore. If you want, you could add another column of `Boolean` type and it can determine if record should be deleted or not when you need to update...Or another option is you would have to keep a reference to the `DataRow` and when removed you can check this object for the `RowState`...

Comment: @Zaggler there is a difference between calling Delete and Remove on the row and in this scenario the row is being deleted and not removed, see this for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03c7a3zb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @alhalama I know, `When you remove a row from the DataTable you can't check the RowState` I was saying remove not delete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

- Declare a `DataTable` at the top of the class
- On the `BeforeRowsUpdate` method, insert a new row into the `DataTable`, which are the values of the row being deleted.
- Optionally, include a confirmation box to ensure they wish to delete the row. If they cancel the deletion, remove the row from the `DataTable`.
- This `DataTable` can then be used for deleting rows in the `UPDATE` query, whilst the grid `DataSource` can handle the `UPSERTS`

Answer (score 0):

The grid will call mark the row as deleted (setting the RowState) and if you are using a TableAdapter then you can simply call Update on the table adapter passing the DataTable to the TableAdapter and it will do the updates in the database.  For example:

```
ultraGrid1.UpdateData()
Me.dbRowsTableAdapter.Update(Me.testDataSet)
```

If you must manually handle updates and you want to get the deleted rows, you could call [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5c0xc84(v=vs.110).aspx) on the DataTable passing in [DataViewRowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataviewrowstate(v=vs.110).aspx).Deleted for the third parameter.

Comment: Hi, do you have any examples of how this would be done, for either method?

Comment: There is an example in this forum thread for using Update on a TableAdapter: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/57161.aspx