# How to display Icon-Index in DataGridView as Icon

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am starting a new project and getting back to an old question.

My application will display the user some information in a `DataGridView`. The `DataGridView` will get its data from a database as `DataTable`. The database-table contains a column called "icon" which is of the type `Integer`. The column "icon" is referring to my `Image Array()`-Index. So when `item("icon").Equals(2)` then ImageArray(2) should be shown.

What is the best way, to make my `DataGridView` display that icon instead of its index?

---

**What I used to use in pseudocode**;

```
Dim dt as DataTable = GetDataFromDatabase()
dt.columns.add("Icon")
For each row as DataRow in dt.Rows
  row.item("Icon") = IconArray(row.Item("IconIndex"))
End For
dt.columns.remove("IconIndex")
MyDataGridView.DataSource = dt
```

Obviously this performes terribly when called every few seconds to keep the data up to date.

---

**What I have also tried:**
- Played around with the CellFormattingEvent
- Played around with DisplayValue-Attribute

Comment: You dont need to loop - use the CellFormatting event to display the desired image either in place of the integer or hide the int column and use your own image column.  `keep the data up to date` seems worth explaining since it has a bearing  especially given that `GetDataFromDatabase` method

Comment: Pre-Defining the columns of my DataGridView might be a good way to go. If i disallow my DataGridView to generate columns it might work out with the cell formatting event. haven't thought about it this way yet.

Comment: you can let it generate columns then hide the int column and add a new imagecolumn

Comment: Keeping data up to date yet always has been creating new datatables and replacing the old datasource which probably isnt the best way - not even a good one at all. GetDataFromDatabase is just an `SQLAdapter.fill(DataTable)`

Comment: definitely not the most efficient.  if you configure it correctly you can simply refresh the data - I presume you are trying to pick up changes from other users?

Comment: You're on point. Yes i do try to pick up changes from other users. Refreshing data instead of creating new sources is my next step to get a better performing application than my last one.

Comment: [Searching values via a datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33701262/1070452) shows how to configure a DataAdapter to be able to refresh.  There is somewhat of a "trick" to removing extra rows on the client who just added them, but that may be down the road

Comment: @Plutonix I know this is chat and not appreciated on SO but a huge thanks. You didn't just help me with that icon problem but also a lot with an other task that I didnt even mention in the question (Refreshing data).