# MySql Change DataGridView Information

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview, dataadapter

I wrote a simple program that populates a Datagrid from `MySQL`.

In one of my columns I have a Boolean (0 or 1)

Once the Datagrid populates with the query I have check boxes for the boolean.

Does anyone know how to use a function when you check the check boxes for the boolean? (This is to send an update of just the boolean of the column.)

To sum up, When the check-box is checked it changes the boolean value from 0 to 1 in the `MySQL` database.

The reason I am having an issue with this is simply because the Datagrid does not populate until I run the application. Therefore, I cannot figure out how to change it while in visual studio.

**How the DGV is populated:**

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

//SQL Query String
string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * FROM `Tasks` WHERE `Completed` = 0";
da.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, conn);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
da.Fill(table);

BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = table;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

Any Help would be grateful.

**Note:**

I've tried using the data configuration manager in VS2015, which resulted in a completely different error that has nothing to do with this. So that's out of the question.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking.  The checkbox represents the state of the bool column in the database, so of course you dont see it until the form loads and DGV populates.  You can of course work with the *data* to do whatever, but it is not at all clear what that is ie `change it while in visual studio`.

Comment: When you click the checkbox, I want it to change the boolean value within the mysql database.

So I'm just trying to figure out how to do so.

Comment: If you use a DataTable as a datasource when they click or change anything, the changes are stored in the DataTable - the DGV is just how we display data to users.  Then using a DataAdapter those changes are written back to the DB.  I suspect you are manually populating the DGV?

Comment: Yes I am manually populating the DGV with code.

Comment: That is how I am doing it. I edited the OP to show you the code. I thought there would be a onClick, onChanged or "onChecked" event I could add for just the boolean column .

Comment: No, that code is populating the DGV using a DataSource - you are not manually adding rows one by one.  If you persist that DataAdapter, you can use it to send changes back to the db.

Comment: Makes logical sense... Guess I got some more googling to do. I guess I was just thinking about it in a different way. 

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33702351/1070452)  `da.Update(table);`

Comment: Thanks a mil, this is what I wanted.

Comment: Well if it helped, by all means click the upvote button for the answer.  Upvoting posts which help or inform you helps others find good answers

Comment: Yeah, I will.. I'm not a professional programmer, but I'm doing it as a project at work. So once I wrap my head around it and make sure it works I'll be sure to up vote.

Comment: I guess I'm not really understanding it for mySQL. Is some documentation for this I can look into to try and understand how to do so better?

Comment: It works exactly the same for MySQL just use MySQL provider objects.  Except DataTable - those are agnostic

Comment: I'm just lost on 'Dim myCB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)' from the response on the old OP. I'm not sure what 'dim' is.

Comment: That is a VB answer; the c# version for MySQL would be `var myCB = new MySQLCommandBuilder(myda);`.  You could run that block of code thru http://converter.telerik.com/ to get the c# syntax.  Generally you can use `var` in place of Dim

Comment: So that's something I seem to not need? So ideally I just need to add `my.DA.Update(myDT);`prior to the 'Fill' which I thought would work, but still it's not updating the database.

Comment: You **do** want a command builder so that the DA knows how to perform updates, inserts and deletes for you.  thats the point

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it more or less invalidates the answer I took the time to post...the edit makes it look like the answer is not needed

Comment: fair enough, again thanks and upvoted your OP too

Comment: Thanks - if you had appended the new edit I would have left it alone, but obviously the missing ()s were apparent via the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to persist that `DataAdapter` it will apply all changes to the underlying `DataTable` for you - multiples in fact:

First class level object to be reused:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

    MySQLDataAdapter myDA;
    DataTable myDT;
    string dbConnStr = "server=..."
```

Then where you initialize everything:

```
string sql = "SELECT A, B, C, D... FROM `Tasks`";

// create the DT
myDT = new DataTable();

// The Adapter can create its own Connection 
//     and SelectCommand
myDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, dbConnStr);

MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDA);

// "teach" the DA how to Update and Add:
myDA.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
myDA.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
myDA.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();

myDA.Fill(myDT);
myDA.FillSchema(myDT, SchemaType.Source);

dgv1.DataSource = myDT;
```

This should create all the needed columns in the DGV and fill it with rows.  That part you have/know.  Click 2-3 checkboxes to change a value, then on a button press add this:

```
int rows = myDA.Update(myDT);
```

Under Debug if you examine the value of `rows`, it will be as many as the number of checkboxes you changed.  It would also INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE any number of rows where that action was needed.

- There is no need to create a connection.  Using the `MySqlDataAdapter(string, string)` constructor overload, you pass the connection string and it creates a connection for itself to use.
- Likewise, it creates a DBCommand object for the SELECT command
- `MySQLCommandBuilder` then uses that `SelectCommand` to create Update, Delete etc commands the `DataAdapter` will use.  This allows you to issue 1 (one) `Update` method call to update 1, 10 or 1000 rows.
- When dealing with a single table, you may not need any other SQL in your app
- The `DataAdapter` has the connection string, so it opens and closes its own connections.

If you define the `PrimaryKey` for the `DataTable`, the DA can also refresh the data - if changes are made to the table outside the app such as by another user, then you can pick up those new rows.  After you update with your own changes:

```
var rows = myDA.Fill(myDT);
```

This is an actual refresh - it will only load new rows and any changes to any existing rows.  Note that the WHERE clause in the original SQL still applies.

As you can see, the `DataAdapter` is capable of much more than just filling `DataTables`;  if that is all you need to do, you can use a `DbCommand` and `DataReader`:

```
myDt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()):
```

Comment: Ok, I had the code pretty much exactly to this prior to the post :) however I'm having an issue with the command builder. the `cb.GetxCommand` is returning an error of `cannot convert method group GetxCommand to non-delegate type MySqlCommand. Did you intend to Invoke a Method?` This was what I couldn't understand ealer when I said That's something I seem not to need...

Comment: They are methods, so they need `()` at the end - the `()` is optional in VB (I started with a quick translation from that VB answer).

Comment: OMG, I'm such a ****head. Works perfectly.. I am so stupid. I can't believe I just asked that question... The whole time I was literally just missing `()` at the end of the method... and I knew what it meant. My brain is on auto pilot... However, I've learned a hell of a lot for datagrids because of you :)

Comment: @ Plutonix, When you talk about if Changes were made via by other users to use the data adapter to refresh the page when this happens.... can you link me to some documentation? Are you referring to Parent and Child Keys via the DB or something else?

Comment: No, if UserA adds a row to the FooBar table, you can 'pick up' those new rows in UserB's app instance using `Fill`, or if UserB change the status of something UserA can pick it up.  Also applies to changes you might make in your UI DB Browser tool.  Its all part of the DbDataAdapeter functionality

Comment: I guess my question is, How do you define a key for the datagrid? I was assuming that you were speaking of foreign keys within the DB.

Comment: You define the PK on the DataTable - the grids are just a user display mechanism.  `myDT.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn[] {dtSample.Columns(0)}`.  If the DA has multiple tables which are related you can define that as well wither as FKeys or Constraints

Comment: A True Refresh means the DT picks up *just the changes* either new rows or new column values.  Without the DA properly configured, you are reloading all the rows every time.  *Another* way to do that is to write a little Table Monitor that fires an event when there are certain changes to a table