# How to not insert the null row in data grid view to sql table vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a data grid view and i insert data in it. When i type a row it automatically open a new row, That's good, but it inserts the null row to the database.

how to not insert it in the database.

My code:

```
con.Open()
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dgv_Deductions.Rows
        cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into SalDeduction (EmpNo, DeductionMonth,DeductionType,Amount,Remarks,tDate) values (" & txt_EmpNo.Text & ",'" & cmb_PaymentMonth.Text & "','" & rw.Cells(0).Value & "','" & rw.Cells(1).Value & "','" & rw.Cells(2).Value & "','" & Now() & "') ", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Sounds like you are executing that code from an event prematurely.  Note that you dont need that code.  A DGV is meant to work with a DataTable, which in turn will update the database for you using a DataAdapter.

Comment: As @Plutonix suggests, you should be using a bound `DataTable`. If you did that then the issue you're currently encountering would not exist.  You should be creating a `DataTable` and binding it to the grid, then calling `Update` on a data adapter to save all the changes from that `DataTable` back to the database.  You can construct the `DataTable` manually or by calling `FillSchema` on the same data adapter.

Comment: [Basics to creating a DataTable and DataAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33702351/1070452)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as asked, you would do this:

```
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows.
                              Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                              Where(Function(dgvr) Not dgvr.IsNewRow)
    '...
Next
```

I would strongly recommend against that though.  You would do better to create a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid, then save all the changes in a batch with a data adapter.  You might construct the `DataTable` manually, e.g.

```
Private table As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With Me.table.Columns
        .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Name", GetType(String))
    End With

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.table
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
          command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name) VALUES (@ID, @Name)", connection),
          adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
        '...

        adapter.Update(Me.table)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use the data adapter to construct the table, e.g.

```
Private table As DataTable
Private adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private builder As SqlCommandBuilder

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.table = New DataTable
    Me.adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here") With {.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey}
    Me.builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.adapter)

    Me.adapter.FillSchema(Me.table, SchemaType.Source)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.table
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.adapter.Update(Me.table)
End Sub
```

That example uses a command builder but you can also build the `InsertCommand` yourself if you want to.

Comment: I used the Datatable example but i got this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this area: .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Name", GetType(String))

Comment: I used the data adapter example and it was good. but now i want the field "Name" to be as a combo box and the data inside it like "John", " Micheal", etc.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the topic of this question.  If this answer addresses the question you asked then you should accept it and if you have a new question then you should post a new question.